# Print/Store each row in matrix - MATLAB

Tags: matlab

I have a 150 X 4 matrix and I wish to loop through the matrix length and print each of the rows out.

This is my attempted code:

```
X = xlsread('filename.csv');

J = X(:, [2:5]) % extracting rows 2 to 5 into a matrix

for i= 0:length(J)
Y = J(i,:); %loop through each row and store it in Y
end;
```

But I keep getting the following error:

```
Subscript indices must either be real positive integers or logicals.
```

Is my approach incorrect? What am I missing out here? I simply want to loop through each row and store it in a variable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MATLAB the indices start at 1 and not at 0, so you should do:

```
for i= 1:length(J)
    Y = J(i,:); %loop through each row and store it in Y
end;
```

In addition, regarding the following line that you wrote:

```
J = X(:, [2:5]) % extracting rows 2 to 5 into a matrix
```

Note that you actually stored in `J` columns 2,3,4,5, of `X` and not rows 2,3,4,5.

Comment: Yes that was my intention, I needed to store columns 2,3,4,5 into J then loop through each row within J. What you mentioned about the indices seems to work, silly mistake from my end, thanks!